# Use each row as a get variable for include?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a notification system and I want to use a kind of platform I've built for viewing the profiles with the ID's found in the database 'friendships' (which keeps track of the sender, recipient and date of a friendship request)

I've been trying to find a way to include this profile module (which uses a $_GET variable to fetch user information), for every row, and I need a way to set a variable for each row and then immediately include that module using the ID, but when I try this, only one appears instead of the 4 requests I have.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div class='item friend'>";

    $_GET['user'] = $row['sender_id'];
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/profile/module.php";
    include_once($path);

    echo "</div>";
}
```

I am aware that setting a variable like this is wrong, but I don't have a clue about how I would go about doing this.

**UPDATE:** After applying Gautum Rai's code, the correct about of divs are showing, but they appear empty.

This is the HTML that generates once I use the original code (which echoes the info of one person).

```
<div class="item friend">
<div class="profile">
    <img class="pic" title="Taswell: Omikron Player" style="background-image: url("/img/badges/omikron.png") !important;" src="/uploads/profile19.jpg?" 2147213591="">
    <p class="username">MyNameIsKnuckles<img class="medal" src="/img/medals/dragonfly.png" title="Queen Of The Hive"></p><br>
    <p class="bio playing">nothin. just waiting for the next omikron build.</p>
</div>
```

**Note:** I already asked something similar to this, but I got comments telling me to join the variables or not use a while loop to fetch assoc. Please provide a relevant answer, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: `include_once` includes a template once...

Comment: Changing it to `include` doesn't change anything, if that's what you meant.

Comment: If the query returns moe than one result, you will get multiple divs output, even if the include is failing somehow. Please update your question with the generated html

Comment: @Steve Something interesting happened after I used Gautum Nui's code, the divs are now correctly display, but no module. I'll provide the HTML in the answer now.

Comment: Ok, while you are editing the questiobn, add the contents of `module.php` as well, it might be doing something odd to kill the loop (eg `exit` or `die`)

Comment: `module.php` is really long and possibly won't fit in the answer, but there is no exit() or die() in it.

Comment: Check, if the `$result` Variable name is reused in your include. If so, then it will override yours, which means, in the next iterration you have nothing left to fetch (because it is closed already). Rename your variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are susing `include_once` which is explicit including the file **once**, and your filename is always the same. Try only using `include`.

Comment: I did, but this doesn't change the result.

Comment: I'm still getting this **one** request from this **one** person. https://imgur.com/a/JSP90

Comment: When you only get **one** div, then maybe you SQL only returned one row? Have you checked this? When you only get one div in your result, then you are doing the loop only once, meaning your `mysqli_fetch_assoc` has no more rows.

Comment: Changing code inside the loop to `echo $row['sender_id']` perfectly displays all of the ID's of people who have added me.

Answer (score 0):

use `file_get_contents()` instead of `include_once`,

your code should be as :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div class='item friend'>";
    $_GET['user'] = $row['sender_id'];
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/profile/module.php";
    file_get_contents($path); // want to print contents just echo it

    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Why? As written, this will do nothing. If the result was saved to a variable, it would contain raw php code, which wouldnt be much use either

Answer (score 0):

There is an awful lot wrong here.

With the exception of $_SESSION, you should never write to superglobals.

You are calling include_once multiple times within a loop - this is wrong. I suspect you really want the content of the incldued file to be processed for each loop iteration - while include (or require) would suffice, this is also wrong. You are making very innefficient use of resources (and probably not separating your application logic and html). A much more correct way to solve the problem would be to define a function in your include file and call that with $row['sender_id'] as an argument.

Comment: So I should be able to set a variable as a row without problem?

Comment: Your code already copies the associative array representing the data record into "$row" if that is what you are asking - but $row is not in scope when the include file is parsed.